# "Changes are not allowed while code is running"

Tags: visual-studio

I am constantly going back and forth between my code in Visual Studio 2015 and my browser.  When I forget to turn off the debugger before trying to make edits I get this error:

> Changes are not allowed while code is running.

It comes with an annoying bleep sound and a popup.  Is there a way to make that go away and have Visual Studio simply stop my code automatically when it clearly sees I am trying to make edits?

It's normally fine, I simply click ok, manually stop my code and then try the edits again.  The problem is when I am on a stubborn piece of code that doesn't want to work and I am going back and forth I sometimes forget to stop the code.  At that point I am frustrated already because of the code and then to get this stupid popup with a bleep sound is enough to send me into a rage of cursing.

Comment: Seems that you don't like Edit + Continue for some mysterious reason.  Sure, [you can disable it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx).

Comment: Or perhaps I am not sure what Edit + Continue is.  I just want VS to stop bleeping their popup every time I try to edit something when I forget to stop the code

Comment: If you do want to use Edit + Continue while modifying the code, you can simply 'pause' the debugger rather than stop. Admittedly it is a royal annoyance, but what can you do if you actually need to use the feature?